# Launch event on click of element but on things inside element

Tags: javascript, stoppropagation

Hello I made drawer which appears when you click on it and then expands it's width, after second click, it back to it's minimalized form, inside this drawer I have table with checkboxes etc which I will use later to filter things. Thing is that if I click on checkbox inside the table, drawer is hiding. How to do it that event which allow for toggling of width of drawer would work only if I click on it except place where is table? As far as I know it should do something with stopPropagation but somehow I was unabled to implement it in working form.

```
<div class="filter_drawer" onclick="show_stat()">
        <Table class="stat_table">
            ...some content
        </Table>
    </div>

function show_stat() {
    event.stopPropagation()
    var stats = document.querySelector('.filter_drawer')
    var table = stats.querySelector('.stat_table')
    var panels = document.querySelector('.main_container')

    stats.classList.toggle('expanded_stat')
    table.classList.toggle('show')
    panels.classList.toggle('expanded_stat_panel')
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the listener to the element properly using Javascript instead, and then you can check if the `event.target` is the `.filter_drawer` element. If so, then it was a click *directly* on the element, and not one of its descendants:

```
document.querySelector('.filter_drawer').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('.filter_drawer')) {
    showStat();
  }
});
```

(If the click was on a descendant element, and not the `filter_drawer` itself, then the `e.target` test won't match)

No need for `stopPropagation`.

Comment: I have joined to project where most onclicks is that way so that's why I keep it like that to not make mess, You are again saving me:) Thank you so much it works!